# Save Openstreetmap, Openlayers output as .png or .svg, server-side

Tags: svg, openstreetmap, server-side, openlayers-3

I'm currently building a web application with Openlayers that draws routes en points of interest on a map. This map needs to be saved to a file on the server (.png of .svg), so it can be embedded in a .pdf file. The route and POI information is available as KML file.
What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

- Directly export your OpenLayers map to a PNG or even a PDF on the client-side (see these two examples: [png export](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/export-map.html) and [pdf export](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/export-pdf.html)).
- Use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to export a HTML page containing an OpenLayers map to a PDF (on the server-side).
- Use [MapFish Print 3](https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish-print) which is a print server to generate PDF reports containing maps. You would create a report template and configuration and then send a print request containing the geo-data that you want to print (e.g. tile layers or GeoJSON data).